# MySQLi вывод записи

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Есть таблица с товарами. 
Выполняю запрос

```html
$products = array();
if ($result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM products')) {
    while($tmp = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $products[] = $tmp;
    }
    $result->close();
}
```

надо вывести на страницу по отдельности например название продукта

```html
 echo $product['title'];
```

выводится последняя запись в массиве.
как сделать чтобы выводилась какая-то конкретная строка?

Comment: `foreach($products as $product){ echo $product['title']; }`

Comment: Так выводит все значчения. А если только одно? Например 2е?

Comment: `foreach($products as $key => $product){ if ($key == 2) { echo $product['title'];} }` $key - нужная вам строка